# SQLite row returned via shell but not in Go

Tags: sqlite, go, go-sqlite3

I have a SQLite query which returns expected results in the shell. However, when I run the same query in my Go program, no values are scanned.

Here is my query:

```
sqlite> select html, text from messages where id="17128ab240e7526e";
|Hey there
```

In this case, `html` is `NULL` and `text` has the string `"Hey there"`. The table has other columns and indexes.

Here is my equivalent Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    filename := "emails.db"
    conn, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    row, err := conn.Query("select html, text from messages where id = ?", "17128ab240e7526e")
    defer row.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    hasRow := row.Next()
    log.Println("Has row:", hasRow)

    var html, text string
    row.Scan(&html, &text)

    log.Println("HTML:", html)
    log.Println("TEXT:", text)
}
```

The output is:

```
$ go run main.go
2020/07/05 21:10:14 Has row: true
2020/07/05 21:10:14 HTML: 
2020/07/05 21:10:14 TEXT:
```

Interestingly, this only happens when the column `html` is null. If `html` is *not* null, then the data is returned as expected, regardless of whether or not the value of the `text` column is null.

What might explain this behavior?

Comment: Tried to test this in my debian box, while searching for documents to  install, found   `sqlite` and `sqlite3` . I think you are using `sqlite`. If that is the case can you try with `sqlite3` ? ( Sorrry if I am wrong !!)

Comment: You cannot scan `NULL` directly into `string`, that will cause `Scan` to return an error which, if you didn't ignore it, would let you know and may have saved you from having to write the question in the first place. You can scan into a `*string` or an `sql.NullString` to handle this case, or, if sqlite has `COALESCE`, you could use that in the query.

Comment: Whichever way you choose to handle `NULL`, you should try hard to never ignore errors.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva! It seems I missed the fact that Scan() returned an error, so I didn't think to check it. Indeed, the error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments I modified the program using `COALESCE`and is working fine.

**Key Point is : Cannot `scan` `NULL`, directly into string,** can overcome this by utilize `Coalesce` function in Query.

```
row, err := conn.Query("select coalesce(html,'is-null'),text from messages where id =?", "17128ab240e7526e")
defer row.Close()
```

Output:

```
arun@debian:stackoverflow$ go run main.go
2020/07/06 10:08:08 Has row: true
HTML: is-null
TEXT: Hey there
```